# what is the proper c++ way to initialize reference member

Tags: c++, reference

my c++ code is:

```
template <typename T>
struct myNode {
    T& cargo;
    myNode<T>(T& cargo) : cargo(cargo) {  }
...
...
};
```

It works.But in the case of `myNode<int>`,I have to build an int variable and a int reference before construct a new myNode object, like this:

```
int A = 1;
int&B = A;
myNode<int>& a = *new myNode<int>(B);
```

I am wondering how to build a myNode object more directly, like this:

```
myNode<int>& a = *new myNode<int>(1);
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: like "this" what? you have changed anything.. also you can pass A, you don't need B in your first example (the "&" is not part of the "type of the parameter", but is "the way you are passing it", so A will type with no problem with "int&")

Comment: It's usually a mistake to have a reference member in the first place

Comment: There is basically never a situation where `*new` is the right thing to do.

Comment: A reference *needs* to refer to another object. If you have an `int&` there needs to be an `int` elsewhere it refers to. Are you sure you wouldn't be better off with `T cargo;` instead?

Comment: The answer is probably *mu*.  It looks like you are trying to use a hammer to thread a needle.  The wrong tool for the job.  But we don't know what the job is, so it appears to me to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Berto99 Sorry for the typo,it's myNode<int>& a = *new myNode<int>(1); .@François Andrieux I assume sometimes "cargo" could be a more complex object like map or list and that's why I am not using T cargo.Besides,reference is safer than pointer and that's why i am not using pointer.But as a noob I am not sure any of my judgement is right.

Comment: @Eljay Sorry for the typo,it's myNode<int>& a = *new myNode<int>(1); . Basically I am trying to build a node for list,with template.

Comment: @François Andrieux Thanks for your help,Could you give me more details about why *new is inappropriate.And how to write it correctly.I have read hours of c++ guide about custom STL template or code style,seems it is way far from enough.

Comment: @M.M Thanks for your help,Could you give me more details about why a reference member is inappropriate.and what is the proper way to build class member.I have read hours of c++ guide about custom STL template or code style,seems it is way far from enough.

Comment: *Basically I am trying to build a node for list, with template.*  There's no need to use references to build a node for list.  You've already gone down the wrong path.  Removes the references, which makes your *What is the proper c++ way to initialize reference member?* is **mu**.

Comment: @YIHU `*new` implies it that you probably will not `delete` the object. If you use `new` you should assign the result of `new` to a pointer like `T * a = new T();` instead of using a reference like `T& my_foo = *new T();`. But in practice, there is rarely a reason to use `new` anymore. Use smart pointers, for example `auto a = std::make_unique<T>();` or `auto a = std::make_shared<T>();`. Note that this does not fix the problem you have with your reference member.

Comment: To answer the question of the title, `myNode<int>& a = *new myNode<int>(*new int(1));` will do what is wanted, but it is very bad code, and is anti-idiomatic C++, and probably will leak memory like a sieve in practice.

Comment: @Eljay I just had a glance at some similar questions. It seems that a reference could also be a class/struct member. I would read those questions thoroughly tomorrow since it's bedtime now (lol). So the question still remains open for me. If you don't mind, please give me some clue about why there's no need to use reference to build a node for list, or should I use pointer or just "T cargo". Thanks anyway o7

Comment: The first question I have is:  who owns the `T` cargo object?  If the `myNode` owns it, then it should either be a `T` or a `std::unique_ptr<T>`.  And if the `myNode` is just "borrowing" it, then it should be a non-owning `T*`.  Finally, if it is federated ownership (which I recommend against; only go there if you **have** to, rather than because it seems easy), then it should be a `std::shared_ptr<T>`.

Comment: Have you check my answer?

Comment: @YIHU a class with reference member cannot have sensible assignment operators, and usually the copy/move constructors will not be sensible. So I would only consider it for singleton classes

Comment: @Berto99 Yes,thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there are a lot going on here... first, it's a bad practice this:

```
T& obj = *new T(...);
```

Because then you need to remember to delete it somewhere, and making it a reference, does no more than increasing the chance that you will forget to delete it.

There is also another problem: reference lifetime follows the original object lifetime, so if you pass that object `a` around your program, you need to be careful, because the `A` object might have been destructed already.

So to solve the first problem (if you don't have to pass that object around the program), you can simply do something like this:

```
myNode<int> a(A);
```

Also keep in mind that as others has already pointer out, you don't need the other statement involving `B`.

However, if you really really really need that "short version", you can use `R value reference`:

```
T& cargo
myNode<T>(T&& param) : param(cargo) {  }
```

Which will "create for you" a reference to that temporary object `1` (be aware that `R value references` don't accept non-temporary object, so you also need to keep the other one constructor)

Note: this is actually "useful" if you are dealing with complex and heavy objects, not `int`

Comment: Looks like you forgot std::move(cargo) in the constructor

Comment: @Tihran cargo is a reference to T, so  i don't it makes any difference casting it to a r value

Comment: I disagree, without a cast to rvalue the move constructor will not be applied. So it won't work for move-only types, like unique_ptr.

Comment: @Tihran there is no move/copy constructor involved here, as i said `cargo` is a class attribute with type `T&` so with `cargo(...) ` you are using the constructor of a reference, not of the type, so there is no move/copy constructor been called, otherwise class attribute of type reference and object had to behave the same

Comment: @Tihran don't worry , no problem

Answer (score 0):

```
int A = 1;
myNode<int>& a = *new myNode<int>(A);
```

The statement `int& B = A;` is not necessary.

`myNode<int>& a = *new myNode<int>(1);` doesn't work due to the type of the member `cargo` of class `myNode`. It requires to be a reference to a variable, not an integer literal.

Comment: You are keeping the memory leak in the initialization?

Comment: There is no memory leak if you write ```delete &a;```. ```a``` is an _alias_ for the object ```*new myNode<int>(A)```. So, deleting ```&a``` will free the memory occupied by the instance of the object myNode.

Comment: I agree with the others that it is not a good practice to use a reference.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about  `myNode<int>& a = *new myNode<int>(1); ` not working. This is just advice, which you can leave as a comment to the question instead. If you mean that the code you posted is the closest thing OP can get to what they want, you should specify that explicitly and include why what they want doesn't work.

Comment: @Andrea Grillo Thanks for your help.Could you please tell me why this is not a good practice if there would not be any memory leak.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I answered before the question was edited. However, I'm going to update my answer according to the new question.

Comment: @YIHU It is not a good practice because you have to remember to free the memory using `delete`. See the @Berto99 well-explained answer.

Comment: *"So, deleting `&a` will [...]"*, **if** that is deleted. I would give better than even odds that someone who uses `*new` has not thought about deleting the pointer later.